Why is the wording different by Arpachshad and Shelach?
In Bereishis 11:12, when recounting the lifespan of the descendants of Noach, it is written:

וְאַרְפַּכְשַׁ֣ד חַ֔י חָמֵ֥שׁ וּשְׁלֹשִׁ֖ים שָׁנָ֑ה וַיּ֖וֹלֶד אֶת־שָֽׁלַח… וְשֶׁ֥לַח חַ֖י שְׁלֹשִׁ֣ים שָׁנָ֑ה וַיּ֖וֹלֶד אֶת־עֵֽבֶר׃

Why specifically about these two does the Torah say חי as opposed to the others about whom it is written ויחי פלג etc.?
(I wondered if it may have something to do with the fact that the Torah already recounted (10:24) the births of Shelach and Eiver, but the birth of Peleg is also written there.)

You are correct with your guess. According to Essay 22 "When did the Famine End"  (Parashas Vayigash) in the book Understanding Rashi by R. Yisrael Isser Zvi Herczeg, there is a rule in the Tanach syntax.

When the narrative tells us of the transpiration of events in chronological order, it takes verbs in the form of the future tense, such as יֵדַע, and has them denote actions in the past by adding the conversive waw prefix to the verb and placing it ahead of the subject.
When the subject appears first and is followed by the verb in the past tense, as is done in Bereshis 4:1: והאדם יָדַע, it indicates that the narrative goes back in time to refer to an event which took place before those that had earlier been discussed.

The story immediately prior to descendants of Shem was the story of the Tower of Bavel. Before that Torah was telling us about descendants of Shem, Bereshis 10:21-31, where it mentioned both Arpachshad and Shelach. At this point, in Bereshis 11:10 the Torah returns to the parashas of descendants of Shem.
Alternatively, there is a midrash Bereshis Rabba 24:3:

בַּר קַפָּרָא פָּתַח (תהלים סט, כט): יִמָּחוּ מִסֵּפֶר חַיִּים וְעִם צַדִּיקִים אַל יִכָּתֵבוּ. יִמָּחוּ מִסֵּפֶר חַיִּים, מִסֵּפֶר תּוֹלְדוֹת שֶׁל מַטָּה. וְעִם צַדִּיקִים אַל יִכָּתֵבוּ, מִסֵּפֶר תּוֹלְדוֹת שֶׁל מַעְלָה. תָּנֵי בַּר קַפָּרָא בְּכָל מָקוֹם שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר חַי, צַדִּיק, (בראשית יא, יב): אַרְפַּכְשַׁד חַי, (בראשית יא, יד): שֶׁלַח חַי. דָּבָר אַחֵר, יִמָּחוּ מִסֵּפֶר חַיִּים, מִסֵּפֶר תּוֹלְדוֹת שֶׁל אָדָם.
Bar Kappara began: [David said of the wicked:] “May they be expunged from the book of life; and not be inscribed with the righteous” (Psalms 69:29). “May they be expunged from the book of life” – from the book of descendants on earth; “and not be inscribed with the righteous” – from the book of descendants on High. Bar Kappara taught: Everywhere that “lived” is stated, it is in reference to a righteous man: “Arpakhshad lived [ḥai]” (Genesis 11:12); “Shelaḥ lived [ḥai]” (Genesis 11:14). Another interpretation, “may they be expunged from the book of life” – from “the book of the descendants of Adam.”


What about Peleg?

@DoubleAA by the birth of Peleg we are tracing the line of Shem.

Peleg was born back in 10:25

Correct. But we already returned to all descendands of Shem, the the parsha preceeding the Tower of Bavel.

If the tower of Bavel was built at the end of Peleg’s life (Rashi 10:25), then Reu, Srug, Nachor, Terach and Avram were all born beforehand. Even if it was at the beginning of his life, he had certainly already been born.

@Yø-cRo correct. However, the Torah does not litterally go back in time, but to the previous parsha, where Shem and Arpachshad were mentioned.

@YDJ …as were Eiver and Peleg…???

@Yø-cRo Double AA also raised this point. By the time we get to Ever and Peleg, we have already been following the parsha of descendands of Shem.

@YDJ I’m not sure I’m understanding what you’re saying. As far as I see it, Arpachshad, Shelach, Eiver and Peleg are all mentioned in the same manner and context (10:22-25). They are all listed after “the children of Shem”.

@Yø-cRo there is an alternative midrash, which I just added.

@YDJ thanks! It is interesting to note, however, that חי is not written about Shem or Eiver.

@YDJ perhaps this is because we already know that they were Tzadikim (presumably from the fact that we call Shem אבי כל בני עבר)

@Yø-cRo yes. I also have some difficulty with midrash Rabba, because from Noach till Avraham generations were provoking Hashem. I would think Shem and Ever were exceptions.
